# How do I print more than 300 lines?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, lines

quick question but I can't find any solution to it. Basically the program below is suppose to square each integer from 1-1000. But when I print it, it cuts off. I can only print 300 lines and after that it cuts it off. For this example, instead of the first line being 1, it's 4, if it is j<301, and it will be 9 if j<302. How can I print 1000 lines is my main question.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    int j;
    double k,sarr[1000];

    for (j=0; j<301; j++)
    {
        k = pow(j,2);
        sarr[j] = k;
        printf("\n%lf",sarr[j]);    
    }

    return(0);
}
```

Comment: How do you read the output?  Are you scrolling back in your terminal as far as you can?  Does your terminal only have 300 lines of scrollback?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. I suspect your terminal only keeps the last 300 lines of the program's output in its line buffer.

Try redirecting the output to a file (or writing the numbers to a file from within your program).

Comment: Yes, cmd.exe on Windows shows only the last few hundred lines. It's very annoying when viewing debug logs.

Answer (score 1):

The first line should be `1` (`= 2^0`) so your output is truncated.

You could change your for-loop to loop over i = 0, ..., 999 - `for (j=0; j<1001; j++)` and redirect the output to a file in order to see the whole output in case you use a terminal.

Run:

```
./program > filename
```

in order to redirect the output of the program to a file called `filename`, which will be saved in your current directory. This file should contain all printed numbers.

Furthermore there is no need for the array itself. Just use a single variable of type `double`.